# Requesting locations permissions always & in background

Tags: location, permissions

Not sure if this is the right place, but I'm needing some other opinions... I'm working on an app that requires location permissions to be 'Always on' and the app also needs to function in the background - we have cases where the app is not foregrounded, and provides push notifications. I'm trying to craft the messaging of a location permissions request when the user first opens the app. Side note: yes, location is fundamental to the core function of the app.

And, of course, I'm trying to find wording that will meet Google or Apple's guidelines.
Are there any other gotchas I'm not thinking of?

I can give an explanation of why we need locations permissions and how it's for core functionality of the app - something that the users in this case would logically understand. My challenge is explaining that we need it while the app is backgrounded - but that is not a concept I think this audience will understand.  Anything I try gets really wordy.

Currently I've got something along the lines of "X app needs your location, even while in the background, to enable its core function: providing X and Y to you lorem ipsum. By declining, you prevent the app from functioning as intended."

Answer (score 2):

I personally don't like warnings that sound like a penalty. To avoid this, I usually put the benefits first, followed by the setbacks, and third, the counterparts, even though they are important for the use of the application.

> Enjoy X and Y by giving the app your location, whether it's active or not. Otherwise, you will prevent its correct operation.

Comment: ah! good point. thank you!

Comment: this should be a sticky in the "UX writing" tag ;)